# Continuously updating UITableView issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar, updating

I have a searchbar in which the user searches for an address. 
Every time the inputed text is changed a selector is called, new addresses are searched and stored into an NSMutableArray. This works perfectly so far.

Under the searchbar I have a UITableView which is called every time by

```
[searchTableView reloadData]
```

after a new address is added into the array.

As soon as the first address is found, put into the array and the searchTableView is called the app crashes with following message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
```

reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Here is the code I am using:

```
 - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{ 

      list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[geoCoder geocodeAddressString:self.addressSearch.text
             completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                 for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
                 {

                     for (int i=0; i<[placemarks count]; i++) {

                         NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[[placemarks objectAtIndex:i]addressDictionary] valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "]];

                         [list addObject:temp];

                         [searchTableView reloadData];


                         NSLog(@"List: %@", list);
                     }

                 }
             }]; 
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableVieww cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

...

if (tableVieww == savedTableView) {

    UIView *bgColor;

    cell = [self.savedTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        bgColor = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        [cell addSubview:bgColor];
        [cell sendSubviewToBack:bgColor];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0){
        bgColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:098.0f/255.0f
                                                  green:211.0f/255.0f
                                                   blue:182.0f/255.0f alpha:0.90f];
    } else {
        bgColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0f/255.0f
                                                  green:089.0f/255.0f
                                                   blue:128.0f/255.0f alpha:0.90f];
    }

}

return cell; 
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Cheers

Comment: - (NSUInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableVieww numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableVieww == searchTableView) {
        return [list count];
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: Shouldn't `savedTableView` be `searchTableView` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: Also, you have used just `savedTableView` and `self.savedTableView`. Make all of them consistent `self.savedTableView`

Comment: I really am that stupid! How could I have overseen that?! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are not returning any cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

The `savedTableView` should be `searchTableView` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

---

You should have else condition -> What happens if `(tableVieww != savedTableView)`?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableVieww cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (tableVieww == savedTableView) {
         ....
    } else {
         // Initialize cell here as well
    }
}
```